# TSql Getting meta data of stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Having simple stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
    @p1IntMandatory INT ,
    @p2IntDefValueZero INT = 0 ,
    @p3VarcharWzValue VARCHAR(MAX) = 'abc' ,
    @p4DateTimeNullable DATETIME = NULL ,
    @p5IntOutWzValueZero INT = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

END;
```

When running this statement to get stored procedure parameters meta-data specially "has_default_value", "default_value" and "is_nullable" columns, I found that their values are invalid.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.parameters
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[ProcedureName]');
```

This is the result:

```
name                    has_default_value   default_value   is_nullable
@p1IntMandatory         0                   NULL            1
@p2IntDefValueZero      0                   NULL            1
@p3VarcharWzValue       0                   NULL            1
@p4DateTimeNullable     0                   NULL            1
@p5IntOutWzValueZero    0                   NULL            1
```

Is there a right way to get valid meta-data about the stored procedure specially these 3 columns?

Comment: Look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173796.aspx

Comment: In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx): SQL Server only maintains default values for CLR objects in this catalog view; therefore, this column has a value of 0 for Transact-SQL objects. To view the default value of a parameter in a Transact-SQL object, query the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view, or use the OBJECT_DEFINITION system function.

Comment: Going to have to parse definition from sys.sql_modules or something similar

Comment: Solution: You need to read the stored procedure as plain text and parse it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a half way start to a hack for you. It's not a solution but too long to comment, but maybe will get you started. It's an attempt to extract your procedure creation up to the 'as'.

```
SELECT
    --charindex('create proc',[definition]) as SubstringStartLocation
    --,charindex('as',substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),len([definition]))) SubStringLength
    substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),charindex('as',substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),len([definition]))) - 1) as ProcCreation
    ,definition as ProcDefinition
FROM    sys.sql_modules 
WHERE definition like '%create proc%'
```

Then you'll have to parse out that column which is where it could get real tricky but hopefully this helps.

Here's taking it a step further...

```
if object_id('tempdb..#procs') is not null drop table #procs

SELECT
    --charindex('create proc',[definition]) as SubstringStartLocation
    --,charindex('as',substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),len([definition]))) SubStringLength
    substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),charindex('as',substring([definition],charindex('create proc',[definition]),len([definition]))) - 1) as ProcCreation
    ,definition as ProcDefinition
into #procs
FROM    sys.sql_modules 
WHERE definition like '%create proc%'


select
    ProcCreation
    ,right(rtrim(ProcCreation),len(ProcCreation) - charindex('@',ProcCreation) + 1) as Variables
from #procs
where ProcCreation like '%@%'
```

Comment: Although this is a trial, but I prefer a proper way instead of heavy parsing the stored procedure myself.

Comment: @MohammedOsman as stated in the documents, they aren't stored anywhere so any solution will have to be custom. I don't know what you call "proper", though.

Comment: How can I depend on parsing the stored procedure text?! This SP parameters (for example) can't be got. `-- =================
-- Author:  
-- Create date: 08/06/2012
-- Description: 
-- EXEC [dbo].[PROCEDURE] @userName = 'Mohammed', @password = 'q+z6QksS1Qg=', @roleId = 1;
-- EXEC [dbo].[PROCEDURE] @userName = 'Mohammed', @password = 'q+z6QksS1Qg=', @roleId = 2;
-- ===========================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE2]
    (
      @userName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      @password NVARCHAR(50) ,
      @roleId INT
    )
AS 
    BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON ;      
    END`

Comment: If it's standard for you to put that comment block in all of your procedures then we can code around that but there is no one perfect solution for everyone